# Why I can't add item to the database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

im working on my web app. Im using .NET and EntityFrameworkCore. I have created migration and database. Simply I just want to add item to the database but I encounter an error when sending a request to this particular endpoint. I attach some of my code below. I also attach link to my github repo https://github.com/szymi-dev/TestRepo

```
[HttpPost("add-product")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> AddProduct(ProductDto productDto)
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = productDto.Name,
            Price = productDto.Price,
            Descripiton = productDto.Descripiton,
            PictureUrl = productDto.PictureUrl
        };

        _context.Products.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return product;
    }
```

Here is productDTO class

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Descripiton { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I have also added some Entity Configurations

```
public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(p => p.PictureUrl).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Descripiton).HasMaxLength(180).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(p => p.Price).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");
        builder.HasOne(p => p.ProductBrand).WithMany().HasForeignKey(k => k.ProductBrandId);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.ProductType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(k => k.ProductTypeId);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.User).WithMany(p => p.Products).HasForeignKey(k => k.UserId);
    }
}
```

Finally im getting " SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'" error in Postman and

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 14), @p1='?' (Size = 6), @p2='?' (Size = 5), @p3='?', @p4='?', @p5='?', @p6='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "Products" ("Descripiton", "Name", "PictureUrl", "Price", "ProductBrandId", "ProductTypeId", "UserId")
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);
SELECT "Id"
FROM "Products"
WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid(); ~ in VScode

Comment: The `Product` type in database has foreign keys that are not fulfilled by your insert statement. What other fields exist on the `Product` type that you are not providing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I see with your example and your schema. Firstly, as mentioned your Product has a ProductType and ProductBrand reference that you will need to set. Typically in your UI you would have something like a drop-down list populated with Types and Brands to select from, so your Product DTO would need a ProductTypeId and ProductBrandId to represent these selections.

Entities can have a FK exposed (Which your entities do appear to have based on the `HasForeignKey` property, so you can set these when creating your product. Otherwise it is generally better to set navigation property references as this validates that the provided IDs are actually a valid product type and brand:

```
var productType = _context.ProductTypes.Single(x => x.ProductTypeId == productDto.ProductTypeId);
var productBrand = _context.ProductBrands.Single(x => x.ProductBrandId == productDto.ProductBrandId);


var product = new Product
{
    Name = productDto.Name,
    Price = productDto.Price,
    Descripiton = productDto.Descripiton,
    PictureUrl = productDto.PictureUrl,
    ProductType = productType,
    ProductBrand = productBrand
};
```

I don't generally recommend having FK properties exposed when you have navigation properties as this forms 2 sources of truth for the relationship. This is generally only an issue when updating, not creating though.

Lastly you have a User reference, which I think may be a bit of a problem depending on what this relationship is actually intended for. A common case for this would be something like tracking a CreatedBy type relationship, though this would be a many-to-one scenario where the user would not bother maintaining a relationship back to the products (and other entities) that they created. Your User has a Products collection defined, so I would take a close look at what this relationship should be. It seems odd that a product would be associated to a single user in a relationship under a user. Where I wanted to associate users to products like this I would typically expect to see a many-to-many relationship where a User has products associated to them, but those products could be associated to many users. (Rather than distinct products assigned exclusively to one user)

As it stands your product has a required User reference, so if this needs to be associated to the current user then I would fetch the current user ID from your Authentication state or session state and assign that to the Product on creation as well. Again either setting the FK or loading a User entity and setting the User navigation property

Answer (score 0):

You should fill ProductBrandId, ProductTypeId and UserId fields in Product object with existing (or freshly added) values to avoid Foreign key constraint violations.